# Designing for WVGA (480 x 800) mdpi screen

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, aspect-ratio, multiscreen

I know this question is old and basic, but still i am in huge confusion for designing layouts for WVGA and FWVGA (large-mdpi 480 X 800) Screens. Currently for hdpi, xhdpi, 7 inch and  10 inch tablets i am creating dimens.xml as follows:

1. values-hdpi
2. values-xhdpi
3. values-sw600dp
4. values-sw720dp

But similarly i just want to create dimensions for WVGA and FWVGA (large-mdpi 480 X 800) Screens. Please mentor me the best practice to do for large-mdpi (i.e. values-large-mdpi). Also if there is any aspect ratio similar like mdpi(1px), hdpi(1.5), xhdpi(2), large-mdpi(?) also highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: WVGA and FWVGA only differ by 54 pixels (480x800 vs 480x854). I'd make a single folder for both. And, at leat on **phones**, this is a `hdpi` resolution, not `mdpi`.

Comment: thats fine but how will you design for those screens??? through layout-large-mdpi???

Comment: See this: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create folder 'values-large' in 'res' folder, and add dimen.xml file in it, which contains values for 5.1" WVGA and 5.4" FWVGA

Comment: Could you please write a sample code for dimes.xml @Dhawal.